# pthread_mutex_t deadlock after package update

Tags: c, multithreading, glibc

we are using pthread_mutex_t to protect a shared memory accessed by different processes.

After the recent update of glibc (https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2017-02/msg00079.html) the code did stop to work, resulting in a deadlock of every involved process.

To put things in context: The code is running for years and has never experienced any issues lately. There were no changes to the codebase and downgrading glibc "solves" the problem.

The scenario is as follows: 
One process creates and hosts the shared memory, the other processes are connected to the same shared memory which is protected by a pthread_mutex_t. The mutex is created with:

```
  int err;
  pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;

  err=pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
  if( err != 0 )
    DIE("initializing mutex attributes failed: %s",strerror(err));

  err=pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
  if( err != 0 )
    ERR("setting mutex attribute ERRORCHECK failed: %s",strerror(err));

  err=pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
  if( err != 0 )
    ERR("setting mutex attribute PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST failed: %s",strerror(err));

  err=pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr,PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  if( err != 0 )
    ERR("setting mutex attribute PROCESS_SHARED failed: %s",strerror(err));

  err=pthread_mutex_init(mutex,&mattr);
  if( err != 0 )
    DIE("initializing mutex failed: %s",strerror(err));
```

and locked with

```
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
```

Everything works as expected as long as each process accesses the shared memory only from ONE of its threads. As soon as any process has another thread accessing the mutex, after a while everything ends up deadlocked.

The value of `mutex->__data.__owner` is always as expected in the first case (the thread id of the thread currently holding the mutex).

In the second case, as soon as a thread 2 of process A wants to lock the mutex while thread 1 of process A has the mutex currently locked, the 'mutex->__data.__owner` ends up beeing some negative gibberish and the mutex cannot be unlocked by any thread.

The mutex corruption happens exactly in the moment of the second lock and not by some other memory corruption mistake (checked with valgrind and hardware gdb).

If the code for locking the mutex is switched to

```
int success = 1;
while ( success != 0 )
{
  err=pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex);
  success = err;
}
```

everything works fine again and no deadlock is happening.

Can anybody tell from this brief scenario where there could be a mistake?

Comment: Does your current code check the return values from `pthread_mutex_lock()`?  Or does it just assume the lock worked and then wind up calling `pthread_mutex_lock()` on a mutex it doesn't own?  And are you *sure* that a thread that unlocks the mutex is the same one that locked it in the first place?

Comment: The return value is checked (therefore its a robust mutex). And there is a function to recover the data if a process died while holding the mutex (however this is not happening, each process is still alive!). We check the thread id which locks and unlocks the mutex and they are the same.

Comment: You say that this is process shared? This needs a special attribute, AFAIR.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Sorry, that part of the code was lost in copy/formatting. The attribute is set correctly and I updated the question.

Comment: First, what's `errno` set to on lock failure when you replace `pthread_mutex_lock()` with your `pthread_mutex_trylock()` loop? Second, assuming you have run into a newly-introduced glibc bug, I'd approach this by first adding significant logging to the shared mutex use, logging each mutex lock/unlock and documenting the process and thread ids - logging to a single log file opened with `O_APPEND` and making each log entry to the file with a single `write()` call.  I'd then test with different types of mutexes - with and without setting `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: if the trylock is unsuccessful, it returns EBUSY as expected. Unfortunately logging is not that easy. The mutex is under heavy load and every unconditional log output in the locking code (even to files) slows the code so much that the deadlock isn't happening anymore.

Comment: @Trevir Could you perhaps log data to a file in a `tmpfs` file system?  It coud use a lot of RAM, but it might be worth trying.  How does running with different combinations of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` effect the deadlocks?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: If `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` is not set, the deadlock isn't happening anymore. I never logged to `tmpfs` but i will look into it.